# Add trendlines on a grouped barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add trendlines across each colour of columns like this:
[What I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMSz.png)

Is this possible? I have tried with geom_line() but it wont let me as you need to have the same number of points as the barplot. this is my current code:

```js
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
o2concplot <- melt(o2conctable[,c('years','mino2conc','meano2conc','maxo2conc')],id.vars = 1)

ggplot(o2concplot,aes(x = years, y = value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + labs(title = "Ocean Dissolved O[2] changes 2008-2018*", x = "Year", y = "Dissolved O[2] (μmolL^-1)", caption = "*Based on data from IMOS") + scale_fill_manual(name = "Key", labels = c("Minimum", "Mean", "Maximum"), values = c("cornflower blue", "light green", "coral2")) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2017, 2018))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `group` in `aes`.

You can use the official documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html)

```
h <- ggplot(nlme::Oxboys, aes(age, height))
# A single line tries to connect all the observations
h + geom_line()
```

gives

[image]

```
h + geom_line(aes(group = Subject))
```

gives

[image]

Comment: this is what i got using years as the group https://i.stack.imgur.com/XId8B.png

Comment: Please create a minimal reproductible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok i got it, i changed the group to the other variable. preferably i would want the lines going from the columns tops but i guess its fine. Now it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqc4R.png   thanks heaps btw